# fixup_bundle : Qt5 segfault at execution

Tags: macos, qt, cmake

I'm testing fixup_bundle in order to create a standalone Qt5 application. Fixup doesn't give me any error but when running my application, I got something like this :

> Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both
>   /Users/rperrot/Prog/exe/Build/src/executables/exe/exe.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
>   and
>   /Users/rperrot/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I understand the issue but I can't find how to solve it in my CMakeLists.txt

I link my exe like this :

```
target_link_libraries( exe Qt5::Widgets Qt5::OpenGL )
```

then when using install command :

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
install( CODE "
      INCLUDE(BundleUtilities)
      fixup_bundle( ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/exe.app \"\" \"\" )" 
      COMPONENT Runtime )
```

Any suggestion ?